# Select an array from an array in perl

Tags: perl

I'd like to do the following in Perl:

```
my @triples=([3,4,5],[5,12,13],[8,5,17],[7,24,25]};
```

Then I want to select one of the four triples at random, then assign the elements of the selection to the variables x, y, and r.

For example, if [3,4,5] is selected at random, assign x= 3, y = 4, r =5.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `my ($x, $y, $r) = @{$triplets[int(rand 4)]}` like this?

Comment: Perfect answer! It works just as a needed it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An integer between 0 and 4 (4 exclusive):

```
int(rand 4).
```

Use this as the array index:

```
$triplets[int(rand 4)]
```

now dereference and assign to your variables:

```
my ($x, $y, $r) = @{$triplets[int(rand 4)]}
```

as @Jim Davids has pointed out, you can drop the `int` and to get a more general approach, you can use `@triplets` in scalar context to get the length of the array.

```
my ($x, $y, $r) =  @{$triplets[rand @triplets]}
```

Comment: Since perl will truncate a float when specified as an array index, you don't need `int`.  And since `@arr` in scalar context returns the size of the array, you could drop the hard-wired `4` and do `...= @{$triplets[rand @$triplets]}`

Comment: @Jim Davids: Thanks I edited that in, but `@$triplets` is an array dereference of `$triplets`, so I replaced it with `@triplets` since `rand` enforces scalar context

Comment: Oh, right, sorry.  Thought I was working with an array _reference_ of array references for a minute there.